# Python, duplicate a directory with automatic rename option

Tags: python-2.7

[SOLVED](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49365013/9434845)
I'm new here, please bear with me :)

I searched the topics, but didn't find what I want exactly.

using Python 2.7,

**I want to duplicate a folder before manipulating it's content, but the duplicate has to be renamed differently every time I run the code.**

(the original folder content will change every day or so, I don't want to change the code every time I try a new content in the original folder, and I don't want to lose the converted files)

my current code:

```
# renaming files in folder by removing any numbers from the name
# the files are pictures where each picture is a letter a,b,c..
# by removing the numbers, the files will be sorted differently
# which will show a hidden message


import os
import shutil

def magicRename():
    # save the current path
    curPath = os.getcwd()
    # make a copy of the folder before processing the files
    shutil.copytree(r"myFolder", r"myFolder_converted")

    filesList = os.listdir(r"myFolder_converted")
    os.chdir(r"myFolder_converted")
    for fileName in filesList:
        print "The file: [" + fileName + "] renamed to: [" + fileName.translate(None, "0123456789") + "]"
        os.rename(fileName, fileName.translate(None, "0123456789"))
        print "check your files now!"
    # back to old path
    os.chdir(curPath)

# call the function
magicRename()
```

I want a way to make the renaming automatic, like: folder_1, folder_2...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Are you just asking how to generate a unique folder name?

Comment: It's likely that it would make more sense in the long run to get familiar with `git`, `subversion` or similar version control tools.

Comment: @glibdud
I simply want to duplicate the folder without giving a new fixed name to it, it must be new every time the code runs. for example: if the folder name is `myfolder` the first run give `myfolder_converted` but a second run should not overwrite that, instead, it should give: `myfolder_converted_2` just an example, I'm not married to this naming system.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt 
yes I know how to use version control, but it doesn't help me here don't you think?

Comment: It seemed to me that you were reinventing that kind of wheel. If your requirements are different, then just ignore my suggestion, that's fine. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a way to do so is to count the number of folders:

```
largest_index = max([0] + [int(f.split('_')[-1]) for f in os.listdir(curPath ) if os.path.isdir(f) and "converted" in f])
new_index = largest_index + 1
new_name = generic_name + '_%d' % new_index
```

Basically this looks for files of the form "myFolder_converted_SOMEINTEGER", finds the largest integer, adds 1 to it and that's the new name!

```
import os
import shutil

def magicRename(folder_to_duplicate):
    # save the current path
    curPath = os.getcwd()
    # make a copy of the folder before processing the files
    all_dirs_in_path = [d for d in os.listdir(curPath ) if os.path.isdir(d)]

    all_converted_dirs_in_path = [d for d in all_dirs_in_path if 'converted' in d]

    largest_index = max([0] + [int(d.split('_')[-1]) for d in all_converted_dirs_in_path])
    new_index = largest_index + 1
    new_name = folder_to_duplicate + '_converted_%d' % new_index
    shutil.copytree(os.path.join(curPath, folder_to_duplicate), os.path.join(curPath, new_name))

    filesList = os.listdir(os.path.join(curPath, new_name))
    os.chdir(os.path.join(curPath, new_name))
    for fileName in filesList:
        print "The file: [" + fileName + "] renamed to: [" + fileName.translate(None, "0123456789") + "]"
        os.rename(fileName, fileName.translate(None, "0123456789"))
        print "check your files now!"
    # back to old path
    os.chdir(curPath)
```

If your files are like:

```
/directory
    other_directory/
```

From `/directory` if you run `magicRename('other_directory')` twice you'll get:

```
/directory
    other_directory/
    other_directory_converted_0/
    other_directory_converted_1/
```

**NOTE**: I have not tested this code, this is just a way to implement what you want, there may be a few typos you should be able to fix them on your own

---

You could have done the same thing with just counting the number of folders. At first glance this seems to be easier and more intuitive than finding the max and adding 1. However if you ever decided to delete one of these folders then the algorithm may try and create a new folder with an existing name, raising an error. Finding the max however insures that no such case can happen.

Comment: I tried to implement this, but got the error:
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'myfiles'`

Comment: Because in the folder you run this you should only have files as "myFolder_converted_0, myFolder_converted_1" so that when splitting on "_" the last argument is a number. But check for the edited answer

Comment: thank you ted for taking the time to help me with this, I really appreciate it. I tried again, the error this time: `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence` I don't know if I'm implementing this the right way. as I mentioned in my question, this is to duplicate the folder not a single file.

Comment: couldn't upvote your answer, `Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.`